# Exporting tab delimited file to Excel with EPPlus

Tags: arrays, excel, vb.net, epplus

I am trying to export to Excel a tab delimited file that contains two columns. I'm not able to find examples that show how to do this with EPPlus. Most examples I have seen pertain to LoadFromDatabase. My guess is to read the file and store the data as an array or an array list and then perform a LoadFromArrays.

The data from the file looks something like this:

RFID        Comments
ABC245      Device added to the system
BBT988      Device not found
GBN471      Device sold

The following is my attempt to write code to perform the export to Excel. At the moment, I am getting a casting error and trying to get around it. What I'm looking for is to get feedback on what's the correct and efficient way of writing the code to perform the action. Thank you in advance!

```
Dim fLoc As String
fLoc = Server.MapPath(".")
Dim tFile As StreamReader
tFile = File.OpenText(fileLoc)
Dim writeLn As String
writeLn = tFile.ReadToEnd
Response.Write(writeLn)

fLoc = Server.MapPath(".") & "/maindirectory" & param1 & param2
tFile = File.OpenText(fileLoc)
writeLn = ""
writeLn = tFile.ReadToEnd 
writeLn = RTrim(writeLn)

Dim aList As New ArrayList
aList.Add(writeLn)

Dim attachment as String
attachment = "attachment; filename=" + "sheet.xlsx"
Dim xlPack As ExcelPackage = New ExcelPackage()
Dim ws As ExcelWorksheet = xlPack.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(sheet)
Dim ms As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()

ws.Cells(1, 1).LoadFromArrays(aList)
xlPack.SaveAs(ms)
ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ExcelTextFormat` to parse the file, which also allows setting some primitive data types for column/cell formatting if needed. For example with this tab-delimited data:

```
Header 1    Header 2
0   03/22/2017 18:03
1   03/23/2017 18:03
2   03/24/2017 18:03
3   03/25/2017 18:03
4   03/26/2017 18:03
```

Generate Excel file:

```
Dim excelTextFormat = New ExcelTextFormat()
excelTextFormat.Delimiter = vbTab
excelTextFormat.DataTypes = New eDataTypes() _
{
    eDataTypes.Number, eDataTypes.DateTime
}

Using package = New ExcelPackage(New FileInfo(output))
    package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("sheet1")
    Dim ws = package.Workbook.Worksheets(1)
    ws.Column(2).Style.Numberformat.Format = "mm/dd/yyyy"
    ws.Cells("A1").LoadFromText(input, excelTextFormat)
    package.Save()
End Using
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hello kuujinbo, this works like a charm. Thank you for all your help with my questions as well as sharing how powerful and flexible EPPlus can be.

Comment: @ChungLee - You're welcome. Now that you have enough reputation, you should probably upvote answers for your questions that you have marked as answered.

Comment: I have just upvoted your answer to this question. I will go ahead and do the same for the other ones. Thanks again!

Comment: @ChungLee - Thank you. And I apologize - should have provided a link for you about accepting answers: [https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235)

Comment: This is very useful. Now I have a better understanding how the system works. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, @kuujinbo is this faster than inserting a data table row by row?

Comment: @DannyJames - Honestly, I've never profiled what you're asking about, so I don't know. Even if one way is faster than the other, you should consider how much more readable one call to `LoadFromText()` is than iterating over `DataTable` rows.

Comment: @kuujinbo, I agree, however when datasets get quite large 1million cells, then processing time on a cpu gets better by a few milliseconds then it all adds up!

Comment: @DannyJames - OK, that makes sense. If you're dealing with a data set that large, you _may_ run into out of memory exceptions with EPPlus. Search here at SO, I vaguely remember a few questions with that issue.